# How to display validation error on TextField when Formik form is submitted without field touch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm having Formik form with validationSchema and input fields which are implemented like this:

```js
<TextField
  error={Boolean(touched.email && errors.email)}
  fullWidth
  helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
  label="Email address"
  name="email"
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  onChange={handleChange}
  required
  value={values.email}
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

If the user touches the field, it will be validated and he will see an error message. However, if he doesn't touch the field and tries to submit the form, validation will prevent it but the error message will not be displayed.

Is it possible to force each field to be touched onSubmit or something else that would cover this case?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your condition to show error is not a good approach, I mean:

```js
helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
```

When the submit button is clicked, you can access to `onSubmit` method and inside the `onSubmit` you can check the form `error` is existed or not, if it is existed so pass a local state and let the component update and with the local state show the `helperText` as error.

Using `touched.email` is not a good approach, specially when you have several inputs. it is not possible to focus all of them in the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your idea. Can you show some example with this approach? Would this approach still use validationSchema? It sounds to me like this would require each input field to have separate local state for error and I would have to validate each field inside onSubmit in addition to validationSchema, or maybe I didn't get the idea.

Comment: @zoranjeremic, you can see [this input component](https://github.com/amerllica/react-warm-starter/blob/master/src/app/components/form/InputText.jsx) and [it's usage](https://github.com/amerllica/react-warm-starter/blob/master/src/app/pages/Login.jsx) with exactly my mindset. if you wanna understand the true usage of formik for your situation I offer you to clone [this repo](https://github.com/amerllica/react-warm-starter) and run it.

Comment: @zoranjeremic, actually, you should make a separate component for forms and use the formik inside them. then use the form components inside your pages.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm using (https://github.com/devias-io/react-material-dashboard/blob/7d30afc788fa4cbacf656e951853f82c52a369a1/src/views/auth/RegisterView.js) and I prefer reusing that approach than changing all forms. Eventually, I figured out that the problem was in my form which used embedded structure of values, e.g. values.address.line1. When I got flatten it, it started working as expected.